# How to mock Android Lifecycle components?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, android-livedata

I am trying to build an Android app following the [recommended design structure](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide).

Let's say, there is a `UserRepository` for handling the users. However, I would like to have certain settings in the app, for example "Show profile picture", "Sort by", etc. I would like to store these settings in a Room database, just like the Users.

According to my understanding, the cleanest way is to have a separate `UserRepository` and a `SettingsRepository`. And of course, the Settings should have a sort of Model, let's call it `SettingsModel`, in order to be able to retrieve the Settings as a `Map` for example. Note, that this is not a `ViewModel`, it has nothing to do with the UI.

Then, the `UserRepository` should implement its own business (handling the users), just like in the example linked above. Besides that, it also should have a dependency of that `SettingsModel`, so that it can easily retrieve the settings, which affect how the Users should be retrieved.

The `SettingsModel` needs to turn the "raw database data" into a map, so that I can reach the settings like this: `settings.show_profile_pictures` and `settings.sort_by`, etc.
To achieve this, I need to extract the data from the `LiveData`, which implies, that I need to observe that `LiveData`, so that I can update the `Map`, whenever the settings change.

And here comes the problem: the `observe()` method needs a `LifecycleOwner`, which I cannot provide in my tests.

**1st attempt:** mock with Mockito

It would be an instrumented test, becase that way I have access to an `Activity`, which is needed to retrieve the DAO.

I am trying to `@Inject` it with Dagger, but the mocking wasn't successful:

```
class SettingsRepositoryTest {

    private lateinit var settingsDao: SettingsDao

    @Mock
    private lateinit var mockLifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner

    @Before
    fun createDb(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(LifecycleOwner::class.java)

        val appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()

        val db = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(appContext, CurrencyConverterDb::class.java).allowMainThreadQueries().build()
        settingsDao = db.settingsDao()

    }

    @Test
    fun testSettingsMap() {

        val repo = SettingsRepository(settingsDao, mockLifecycleOwner) // throws the exception here

    }
}
```

The exception:

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property mockLifecycleOwner has not been initialized
at com.helmet91.currencyconverter.repositories.SettingsRepositoryTestInst.testSettingsMap(SettingsRepositoryTestInst.kt:46)
```

**2nd attempt:** use Roboelectric to create an `AppCompatActivity`, which is in fact a `LifecycleOwner`.

It is not an instrumented test, because Roboelectric doesn't work in the androidTest environment.

The `Activity` still has to be mocked, however, it throws a `NullPointerException`. The only way I can think of, is to go through this Exception stack, and mock everything in it, if it's even possible at all. But that sounds insane to me. There has to be a better solution.

```
class SettingsRepositoryTest {

    private lateinit var settingsDao: SettingsDao
    private lateinit var activity: AppCompatActivity

    @Before
    fun createDb(){
        val built = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity::class.java) // throws the exception here
        val created = built.create()
        val controller = created.start()
        activity = controller.get() as AppCompatActivity

        val db = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(activity, CurrencyConverterDb::class.java).allowMainThreadQueries().build()
        settingsDao = db.settingsDao()

    }

    @Test
    fun testSettingsMap() {

        val repo = SettingsRepository(settingsDao, activity)

        val settingsMap = repo.getSettings()

        val settingsEntity = Settings(1, "show_flags", "1", "bool")

        settingsDao.insert(settingsEntity)

        assertTrue(settingsMap.show_flags)
    }
}
```

The exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.ShadowImpl.extract(ShadowImpl.java:17)
    at org.robolectric.shadow.api.Shadow.extract(Shadow.java:25)
    at org.robolectric.Shadows.shadowOf(Shadows.java:1215)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.CoreShadowsAdapter.getMainLooper(CoreShadowsAdapter.java:23)
    at org.robolectric.android.controller.ComponentController.<init>(ComponentController.java:29)
    at org.robolectric.android.controller.ComponentController.<init>(ComponentController.java:21)
    at org.robolectric.android.controller.ActivityController.<init>(ActivityController.java:33)
    at org.robolectric.android.controller.ActivityController.of(ActivityController.java:25)
    at org.robolectric.Robolectric.buildActivity(Robolectric.java:97)
    at org.robolectric.Robolectric.buildActivity(Robolectric.java:93)
    at com.helmet91.currencyconverter.repositories.SettingsRepositoryTest.createDb(SettingsRepositoryTest.kt:29)
```

Is it really impossible to test anything, that involves Lifecycle components?

Comment: Have you tried something like this: https://proandroiddev.com/how-to-unit-test-livedata-and-lifecycle-components-8a0af41c90d9?

Comment: @MatPag Oh thank you for reminding. Yes, I tried that as well, I forgot to include it in the post. I will edit it.

Comment: SettingsRepository should expose liveData objects, it not need a lifecycle.Then use the method `observeForever` that don't need lifecycle object